# Legitimative adoption and French nationality

Tags: immigration, france, french-citizens, nationality

My father was born to a French woman in Orleans, France, but was abandoned and adopted by an American soldier and his wife. The acte de naissance of 1958 says that he "will cease to belong to his natural family." I assume this is a legitimative adoption which was replaced with plenary adoption in 1966. I want to know if my father lost his French citizenship/nationality as a result of this adoption.

Comment: For what practical purpose are you trying to get this info? Regardless of the impact of adoption on his nationality, if your father's been more than 50 years in the US, doesn't have any French passport, ID card, etc., he may have lost his French citizenship anyway.

Comment: Thank you for this response. I am asking to understand whether I am a French citizen. The 50 year issue does not pertain to me or my father, as he died well before the expiration of 50 years.

Comment: The service de l'etat Civil confirmed that my father "est toujours francaise" and they advised me to complete a CNF. I'm still a bit curious if anyone knows if the fact of this kind of adoption will cause any difficulty.

Comment: All the information I could dig up pertained to adoption by French parents of foreign nationals. Being adopted doesn't seem to be listed explicitly as a rationale for losing one's French nationality, but I couldn't find it spelled out. So it's possible your dad was still French, but I guess you'll only know by asking.

Comment: @qoba The father most definitely hasn't lost his citizenship. His children might have.

Comment: No clear resolution without significant research and effort by the OP.